# Failing person creation spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I have written an integration test to create a new person in my Rails app. The registration form (using Devise) works just fine in development and in production, but I wanted to have a spec for it too.

However the spec is failing, and I'm seeing some strange behavior. This spec is the only one failing for me - all others pass.

I notice in the log that in dev/prod the log shows

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create
```

and that the parameters passed are

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sRvErzoB/SwegGe/hNRp3J4zJ7i9Rk5yVY0sHymgW7M=", "person"=>{"first_name"=>"Warbling", "last_name"=>"Goose", "email"=>"goose@test.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up!"}
```

On the other hand when the spec is run the test log shows

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
```

and that the parameters passed are

```
Parameters: {"person"=>{"first_name"=>"Warbling", "last_name"=>"Goose", "email"=>"goose@test.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up!"}
```

Interestingly, I don't see the authenticity_token being passed in the test log?

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.5.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.99.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.4.4'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'populator'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'spring', '1.1.3'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
end

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'figaro', '1.0.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc2'
gem 'devise', '3.4.1'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

Here's my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'faker'
require 'email_spec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller

  # Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include EmailSpec::Helpers
  config.include EmailSpec::Matchers

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    require "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"
  end
end
```

The spec itself:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

feature 'Person creates an account' do

  scenario 'Successfully' do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Sign up'
    fill_in_with_valid_data
    expect { click_button 'Sign up!' }.to change(Person, :count).by(1)
    email = open_email('goose@test.co')
    click_first_link_in_email
    expect(page).to have_content( "Your email has been confirmed.")
  end

  def fill_in_with_valid_data(attributes = {})
    fill_in 'person_first_name', :with => 'Warbling'
    fill_in 'person_last_name', :with => 'Goose'
    fill_in 'person_email', :with => 'goose@test.co'
    fill_in 'person_password', :with => 'password'
    fill_in 'person_password_confirmation', :with => 'password'
  end
end
```

The log output of the spec:

```
Started GET "/people/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-31 14:31:35 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/application (31.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 87.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
Started GET "/people/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-31 14:31:35 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.slim within layouts/application (8.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people"
Started GET "/people/sign_up?person[first_name]=Warbling&person[last_name]=Goose&person[email]=goose%40test.co&person[password]=[FILTERED]&person[password_confirmation]=[FILTERED]&commit=Sign+up%21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-31 14:31:35 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"person"=>{"first_name"=>"Warbling", "last_name"=>"Goose", "email"=>"goose@test.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up!"}
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.slim within layouts/application (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people"
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

And in case it's helpful, the registration form:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .container
    = devise_error_messages!
    #signupbox.mainbox.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2 style=("margin-top:50px")
      .panel.panel-info
        .panel-heading
          .panel-title Sign Up
          div style=("float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-17px")
            = link_to "Sign in", new_person_session_path
        .panel-body style="padding-top:30px"
          form#signupform.form-horizontal role="form"
            .input-group style=("margin-bottom: 25px")
              span.input-group-addon
                i.fa.fa-user.fa-fw
              = f.input_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First name', :autofocus => true, class: 'login-username form-control'
            .input-group style=("margin-bottom: 25px")
              span.input-group-addon
                i.fa.fa-user.fa-fw
              = f.input_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Last name', class: 'login-username form-control'
            .input-group style=("margin-bottom: 25px")
              span.input-group-addon
                i.fa.fa-paper-plane.fa-fw
              = f.input_field :email, placeholder: 'Email address', class: 'login-email form-control'
            .input-group style=("margin-bottom: 25px")
              span.input-group-addon
                i.fa.fa-key.fa-fw
              = f.input_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', class: 'login-password form-control'
            .input-group style=("margin-bottom: 25px")
              span.input-group-addon
                i.fa.fa-key.fa-fw
              = f.input_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'off', placeholder: 'Confirm your password', class: 'login-password-confirmation form-control'
            .form-group style="margin-top:10px"
              /! Button
              .col-sm-12.controls
                = f.submit 'Sign up!', :class => 'btn-login btn btn-success'
```

and the output of the rspec test:

```
rspec spec/features/person_signup_spec.rb 

Person creates an account
  Successfully (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Person creates an account Successfully
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button 'Sign up!' }.to change(Person, :count).by(1)
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/features/person_signup_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.22247 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/person_signup_spec.rb:9 # Person creates an account Successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks as though you have a form inside of a form.

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  ...
  form#signupform.form-horizontal role="form"
  ...
```

Your spec is likely using the default action for the 2nd embedded form.  Since there is no action attribute specified on the second embedded form, it defaults to the current page you are on `/people/sign_up`and since there is no method attribute on the second form it defaults to a `GET` request when the form is submitted.

This is why you are seeing the form being submitted as a GET request to the same sign up page.